# Sending a parameter from node file to package.json script command

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

This is a file named myFile.js I execute with node:

```
var aa = `npm run build -- --main=src/` + (component === `widget` ? `thisPath/` : ``) + `${component}/myFile.ts`;
execSync(`${aa} `);
```

This is in a foreach loop, value of 'component' changes in each loop.

And this is the build command in my package.json:

```
"build": "ng build --aot --outputHashing=\"all\" --sourceMap=false --vendorChunk=false --extra-webpack-config elements-webpack.config.js --single-bundle"
```

And this is my elements-webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

console.log(process.argv);
var pathData = process.argv[10];

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: pathData === 'main' ? '[name].[contenthash].js' : '[name].[contenthash].js',
    jsonpFunction: 'myElements-' + uuidv1(),
    library: 'elements'
  },
  externals: {
    "rxjs": "rxjs",
    "@angular/core": "ng.core",
    "@angular/common": "ng.common",
    "@angular/common/http": "ng.common.http",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "ng.platformBrowserDynamic",
    "@angular/compiler": "ng.compiler",
    "@angular/elements": "ng.elements",
    "@angular/forms": "ng.forms",
    "@angular/router": "ng.router"
  }
};
```

What I want to do is send a parameter from myFile.js to the command in package.json so that I get it in the webpack config file. The parameter is the value of the 'component' variable.

I think it should look like this:

```
var aa = `npm run build -- --main=src/` + (component === `widget` ? `thisPath/` : ``) + `${component}/myFile.ts` + ` ${component}`;
```

But then I dont know how to catch it in package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then I dont know how to catch it in package.json.

You don't need to do any special handling in `package.json` to pass arguments. If the invocation uses `--`, then everything after `--` will be an argument added to the command.

Example package.json:

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ls"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

From the command line:

```
$ npm run build

> temp@1.0.0 build
> ls

package.json
$
```

Cool. Now if we want to pass the `-a` option to `ls`, we can do it but only after `--`.

So this doesn't work:

```
$ npm run build -a
> temp@1.0.0 build
> ls

package.json
$
```

But this works:

```
$ npm run build -- -a

> temp@1.0.0 build
> ls "-a"

.       ..      package.json
$
```